# Steema TeeChart Horizontal Bar Series. How to use Stacked100?

Tags: delphi, vcl

I wish to show a number of stacked values in a horizontal bar series. I can show the values stacked with their individual values OK, but I am unable to show them as mbStacked100 (so that the values take up 100% of the graph width) I have several values in the series, each with a corresponding color.

This code works to add the individual values, but I have not been able to successfully use mbStacked100 to show the series as a percentage rather than the individual values.

```
procedure TForm4.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
Rnd : Integer;
i : Integer;
j : Integer;
MyColour : TColor;
HSeries : array of THorizBarSeries; {added here to clarify}
begin
{attempt to add a data set to the bar chart}
SetLength(HSeries, 0);
Chart1.RemoveAllSeries;
Chart1.LeftAxis.Items.Clear;
series1.StackGroup := 0;
Chart1.LeftAxis.Items.Clear;
Chart1.LeftAxis.Items.Count := 0;
Chart1.Pages.MaxPointsPerPage := 16; 
SetLength(HSeries, 150);
for i := 0 to 150 do
  begin
  HSeries[i] := THorizBarSeries.Create(Chart1);
  Hseries[i].MultiBar := mbNone;

//  case RG1.ItemIndex of
//    0 : Hseries[i].MultiBar := mbNone;
//    1 : Hseries[i].MultiBar := mbStacked100;
//  end;

  HSeries[i].StackGroup := i;
  HSeries[i].Marks.Visible := False;
  HSeries[i].BarWidthPercent := 90;
  MyColour := clGreen;
  Rnd := Random(45);
  Rnd := 45 + Rnd;
  HSeries[i].AddX(Rnd, '', MyColour);
  Hseries[i].MultiBar := mbSelfStack; {prepare for multi-stack}

  Chart1.LeftAxis.Items.Add(i);
  Chart1.LeftAxis.Items.Item[i].Text:= IntToStr(151-i)+' GT:'+IntToStr(Rnd);  

  {draw the yellow and red}
  for j := 2 to 3 do
    begin
    if j = 2 then myColour := clYellow
    else MyColour := clRed;
    HSeries[i].AddX(j*2, '', MyColour);
    end;

  Chart1.AddSeries(HSeries[i]);

  end; {for i}

end;
{________________________________________________________________________}
```

I have tried many ways to use mbStacked100 so that the image is shown as 100%, but none successfully.
The above code produces this: 
[Horizontal Stacked bars](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yf58nu07jrnmxmv/2018-10-12_18-40-58.jpg?dl=0)

I could not find any usable sample code including on the Steema web site and documentation. 
Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: All series should have MultiBar set to mbStacked100.  Your code is missing the definition of `HSeries` so can't be used as is.

Comment: My Bad. HSeries is defined as: var HSeries : array of THorizBarSeries; (it's global but I added it to the routine for clarify.)

Comment: With all series set to mbStacked100 I get this display: [link]https://www.dropbox.com/s/l1vr3eqbpqreb4b/2018-10-13_15-45-45.jpg[/link] which is clearly not correct.